# Можно ли как то упростить данный код или подправить данные json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Задача связана именно с json объектом не использовав субд.
Есть объект данных:

```
{
  [section]: {
    [category]: [{id: 1, name: 'Product-1'}, {id: 2, name: 'Product-2'}],
    [category]: [{id: 3, name: 'Product-3'}],
  },
  [section]: {
    [category]: [{id: 4, name: 'Product-4'}],
  }
}
```

По этим данным я делаю такую маршрутизацию

```
GET /api/product/:id // Получение информаций о продукте
```

Для получения информаций о продукте, я написал такой код

```
exports.findById = (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const result = [];
    Object.values(data).forEach((section) => {
        Object.values(section).forEach((category) => {
            category.forEach((product) => {
                if (product.id == id) result.push(product);
            });
        });
    });

    if (result.length > 0) return res.status(200).json(result[0]);

    return res.status(404).json({ ok: false, message: 'Not Found' });
};
```

Протестировав данный код, я получил следующие результаты:

- GET /api/product/1 Результат ответа по времени 3ms
- GET /api/product/99 Результат ответа по времени 9ms
  И меня смущает разница в 6ms, видимо это он обрабатывает повторяющиеся данные. И подумал может изменить структуру json с api маршрутизаций или еще как то код написать, а может зря переживаю?

Comment: такая структура была бы оправдана если бы в каждой категории id всегда начинались бы заново, судя по твоему объекту у всех продуктов id уникальные, значит проще сделать id в качестве ключа. Поиск тоже по id.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, у вас постоянно совершается много пустой работы. Возможно, вам стоит создать что-то вроде вспомогательной структуры типа [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), один раз пройтись по `data` и заполнить `Map` ключами из `id` и значениями со ссылками на объекты. Тогда вы сможете мгновенно получать нужный объект по `id` без перебора вложенных структур. `Map` можно обновлять каждый раз, как обновляется ваша основная структура `data`, если она вам необходима в таком виде для других нужд.